# Selenium link with class

Tags: css, selenium

I need to click all dinamic page links with same @class.Is there a way to do that in selenium?

Comment: What language you are using? Or you build your test via selenium Rde?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using element position in xPath like a[@class='sameClass'][1]?

Answer (score 0):

I would get a count of the HTML elements with the class using getxpathcount.  Then loop over those elements and within the loop perform a click.  I've written some functions that do this.  Basically get an xpath count. Loop over the count to get the xpath's, stuff into an array.  Loop over array with a click.